# How to use a multi-variable string in the name of a variable in pure js

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I'm a huge JS nub and still getting used to the syntactical nuances. Essentially, I'm looking to reduce the following to a single line:

```
if (player==1) {variable1[arrayposition] = thisvalue;}

if (player==2) {variable2[arrayposition] = thisvalue;}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really have to, then:

```
[variable1, variable2][player-1][arrayposition] = thisvalue;
//this is a one-liner. Short but hard to read.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/c3Lxn/

However the way you are doing it right now is okay. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: This is correct. Whoever downvoted should be banned from downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator to define the "variable" to use and, assuming the array position and value are the same use it all on one line:

```
(player === 1 ? variable1 : variable2)[arrayposition] = thisvalue;
```

I am assuming `player` can only be equal to `1` or `2`. If you have to, you should `null` check or check for other values, you should do this elsewhere or additionally.

Comment: this has the same if structure, its not shorter. The other answer by Derek is better because it avoids the "if"

Comment: @ZigMandel Yes, it does have the same if structure, but the question was to make the two liner a single line, which this does. Also, my answer avoids creating a new array unlike Derek's... why look down on using an "if"?

Comment: To be fair this *is* in one line. +1 for you.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks. To note, it's also a lot faster (at least, in Chrome 33) http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-ternary I do like the creativity of your answer though, never would have solved it that way.

Comment: whats the point of measuring code by number of lines? Derek's answer avoid the "if" which is important because allows an optimizer to perform faster (at least in a compiled language like c, thou I admit I havent seen what happens in js), Yes creating the array takes a perf hit too but it depends on the situation, maybe it can be created once or as global. Again im basing this on experience with compiled code, not js. See this for more on branches and how compilers try to optimize them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Comment: @ZigMandel So your assessment of a "better" answer is not based within the context of question? Again, I like Derek's answer and I can't comment on if it's "better" in another language, but the jsperf above shows it's over 70% slower (in Chrome 33). Yes, the array could be pre-created/global, but now you're outside the one-line solution the OP asked for. There are tons of ways to solve this question, but you shouldn't assume one is "better" just b/c it is so in a different context. Now, maybe if I had put `eval('variable'+player+'[arrayposition] = thisvalue');` it'd be a different story...

Comment: yes, you are right, but on the same line, you cant assess the performance of code by just trying a single line, the code always has context. Might be different if you have it inside a tight loop or not, etc. Yes its also true that Im basing on experience with a different language, but if js compilers currently dont have branch prediction, I am sure it will be eventually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using a map, this support numbers and strings

```
({
    "1" : variable1,
    "2" : variable2,
})[player+''][arrayPosition] = thisValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both those answers! I learned useful things I didn't know. What I was really hoping was I could have an array within an array (but I couldn't get this syntax to fly):

variable[playernumber][arrayposition] = thisvalue;

Is it possible I'm approaching the problem inefficiently and should instead be thinking of "variable" as an object which contains an array?

Comment: perhaps something like: variable[playernumber].subvariable[arrayposition]